# Is it possible to combine RSA keys such as 2 private keys is required?

Tags: rsa

Imagine I have 2 smart cards, both with its own secure generator for RSA 2048 keypairs.

I want to make a cryptosystem such as possession of both of the smart cards is required to decrypt a message.

To avoid a extremely large public key definition, I want to combine Pub1 and Pub2 into PubCombined, such as, so both Priv1 and Priv2 is required to decrypt a message encrypted with PubCombined.

Note: The message must be able to be decrypted in succession, as the keys are non-exportable, eg EncryptedData --> priv1 --(partially decrypted data)--> priv2 --> PlainText.

Any ideas? I know that this are possible with elliptic curve signatures, but the question is how I use them for cryptography, so I think RSA is the only way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to have each card have its own RSA public/private key, and just use both to do key transport, namely: $\DeclareMathOperator{\rsa}{RSA}\DeclareMathOperator{\aes}{AES}\DeclareMathOperator{\pub}{pub}\DeclareMathOperator{\priv}{priv}$

- Card A has RSA public key $\pub_A$ (which it exports) and RSA private key $\priv_A$ which it keeps secret
- Card B has RSA public key $\pub_B$ and $\priv_B$, and it exports $\pub_B$
- When someone wants to encrypt a message $M$, it selects two random values $r_1$ and $r_2$; it encrypts $r_1$ with $\pub_A$, and encrypts $r_2$ with $\pub_B$; it then uses $r_1 \oplus r_2$ to AES encrypt the actual message.  Hence, the ciphertext will consist of $$\rsa_{\pub_A}(r_1) || \rsa_{\pub_B}(r_2) || \aes_{r_1 \oplus r_2}( M )$$
- Decryption is obvious; we ask card A to decrypt $\rsa_{\pub_A}(r_1)$; ask card B to decrypt $\rsa_{\pub_B}(r_2)$; then with $r_1, r_2$ in hand, we AES decrypt the message.

Nice things about this are a) you're using the smart cards as they were designed, and b) it's pretty obvious why this meets the security requirements.

> To avoid a extremely large public key definition

The above would have a public key which is slightly larger than 512 bytes; is that 'extremely large'???

Now, one could come up with something fancier; such as a three exponent RSA, with the two cards sharing a modulus, and with exponents $e \cdot d_A \cdot d_B \equiv 1 \pmod {\lambda(n)}$; that'd work pretty much how you outlined.  However it's more work (it's not immediately obvious who would compute $d_A, d_B$), is it worth it to shave off a few hundred bytes from the public key?

Comment: Well, we agree :) I was just checking if there was a dupe somewhere.

Comment: The ciphertext must also keep its length as they are QR codes (too big QR codes are a pain to scan reliable). Im currently building an authentication app. Currently its using the TrustZone. But I want to also add Smartcard support, which will be used in series with the TrustZone storage, but still keep the same public key size and cipher message size. So im talking about a math combining solution.

Comment: I think the "fancy" solution is not that difficult to use, and the numbers are created during KeyGen (just pick $d_A$ randomly) and work just like regluar RSA decryption. Another feature in this case: Knowing $n,e,d$ allows factorization of $n$, but in this case neither card A nor card B can use that (based on the knowledge of a multiple of $\phi(n)$).

Comment: @sebastiannielsen It sounds like you actually require that the size of the *ciphertext* doesn't increase - the size of the public and private keys doesn't matter. But in general: encryption is quite likely the wrong tool if your goal is authentication. And the best way to reduce the size of ciphertexts, signatures, etc. is either using symmetric crypto (if possible) or elliptic curves - e.g. 2 MACs or 2 ECDSA signatures would require less space than one RSA ciphertext.

Comment: The public/private keys should have the same size too. The reason is that I want to avoid to have redesign the backend to handle the double encryption. If I could combine the 2 public keys into one, I could use one encryption step, but still get the added security of 2 smartcards. Im most interested in the e * dA * dB = 1 (mod y(n)) solution (sorry for the "wrong" symbols, can't use them in comment) - do you have some in-depth info about it

Comment: The app works like this: The server encrypts a one-time passcode, with the user's public key. The user's app decrypt the encrypted QR, rendering the one-time passcode on-screen. The user enters this. Using digital ECDSA signatures would become TEDIOUS TYPING of the response. It must be some encryption scheme, supported by most smartcards & Android crypto provider, so the response codes are as short as the server wants them to be.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the public keys using an algorithm doesn't make sense. If you want you can create 2 self signed certificates and put them in a trust store. Or you can just encode the public keys to PKCS#1 format and put both in an ASN.1 sequence. Or just concatenate the PEM encoded key blobs. Whatever way you think is best.

As for the encryption: you can simply encrypt two separate AES sized keys. Then you can combine these keys using XOR and encrypt the message with it. The only issue with that is that you have additional, decrypted keys to worry about.

You can also first generate an AES key and encrypt the message with that. Then you can generate a random key, XOR it with the AES key and then encrypt the random key and the result after XOR'ing with the AES key.

You can use the same scheme using ECIES of course, this isn't limited to RSA at all.